# Twitter Bootstrap doesn't show up in my Rails app (using the Gem)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I use Twitter Bootstrap in my Rails application, but for some reason it has stopped showing up and the app is now a mess without bootstrap. I use the Twitter Bootstrap Gem in my Gemfile by saying this:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :github => 'seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails', :\
ref => "85ad702d75abb2338c3be87ab1a970a3ba9a1ab0"
```

Once I bundle install and locate where Twitter Bootstrap installed to (using bundle show twitter-bootstrap-rails), Rails tells me that it's installed at /my_app_path/target/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-85ad702d75ab.

In my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less stylesheet (where I use bootstrap), I have the following commands that should be importing bootstrap but fail:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";
```

This same code is running on a server but won't run on my machine and I can't figure out why - Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: What does your layout file look like?

Comment: @Brian, which part do you specifically need? It's too long to type in. Basically, the head is a a stylesheet_link_tag and a bunch of favicon_link_tags and the body is a navbar followed by bootstrap_flash and yield. And then javascripts at the bottom of the file

Comment: ah, ok, wasn't sure if you had included the proper js/css or not. So, it work on your server, but not localhost?

Comment: Yep, can't figure out why not for the life of me. I'm using the right Gem without issues, the bootstrap just doesn't work. Probably a longshot, but could it be something to do with the folder names in the location where the gem installed? I installed it in target but I did notice that the folder names aren't the same as the import statement.